# Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: function, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I'm working on a web app with Vue.js and I get this error when I set up my routing in my route.js file, I don't see where is the problem.
Is there someone that can help with this issue thanks?

```
        router.js?41cb:8 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
        at eval (router.js?41cb:8)
        at Module../src/router.js (app.js:1349)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
        at fn (app.js:151)
        at eval (main.js:11)
        at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1337)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
        at fn (app.js:151)
        at Object.1 (app.js:1362)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    eval @ router.js?41cb:8
    ./src/router.js @ app.js:1349
    __webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
```

Here is my code below.

```
        import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
        import MusicApp from './components/home/MusicApp.vue';
        import PageNotFound from './components/PageNotFound.vue';
        
        const router = createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory(),
             routes: [
                 {path: '/', redirect: '/home'},
                 {path: '/home', component: MusicApp},
                 {path: '/:notFound(.*)', component: PageNotFound}
            ],
        });
        
        export default router;
```

Comment: Anything change if you do `const routerHistory = createWebHistory()` right after your imports section, then setting `history` in your `createRouter` block to `routerHistory`, instead of to the `createWebHistory` method directly?

Comment: I also have this message in my terminal "export 'createWebHistory' was not found in 'vue-router'

Comment: I re-install vue-router@next And it is working now .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using older version of vue-router with Vue3.
Vue3 only works with alpha version.
To install alpha version run:
npm install vue-router@next

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after restart the server it was fixed, just hit:

> npm run serve